# Detect boxes for dots and boxes game for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, cgpath

I'm trying to make a little dots and boxes game for the iPhone using sprite kit. 
I wrote the code to create the dots and connect them with a line but i have no
idea how to detect the box when the four dots are connected? This is my code for now:

```
    -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        [self gameScene];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)gameScene {

    int dotNameCount = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < dotsInARow * dotsInACol; i++) {

        dot = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
        dot.position = CGPointMake(40+i%dotsInARow*60, 120+i/dotsInACol*60);
        dot.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot%i", dotNameCount];
        dotNameCount ++;
        dot.zPosition = 2;
        [self addChild:dot];
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if ([[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene].name length] == 0) { } else {

        pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, [self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene].position.x, [self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene].position.y);
        selectedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];
        selectedNode.color = [SKColor blueColor];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if ([[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene].name length] == 0) { } else {

   CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL,[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene].position.x, [self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene].position.y);

        selectedNode = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];
        selectedNode.color = [SKColor blueColor];

        pathNode = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
        pathNode.path = pathToDraw;
        pathNode.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
        pathNode.fillColor = [SKColor greenColor];
        pathNode.zPosition = 1;
        [self addChild:pathNode];
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Detect WHEN the user has come "full box" by connecting the dots in any sequence or order (as long as they become a box?), or something different?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to detect when the user completes a full box.

Comment: Note that the completed box might be on either side of the line that was just clicked--or it might complete two at once. These shared edges make it difficult to create a good, self-consistent conceptual model. See here for one way to do it in JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30387118/1593924 . In a nutshell, I have a 2D array of cell objects (w x h) who usually share a couple of sides with other cells (i.e. both point to the same Edge object), and another 2D array for the view model (2w+1 x 2h+1) that represents vertices, edges, and cells all in a single array.

Comment: In my model (the pure array of cells), a cell is 'filled' if all of the Edge objects that it links to are 'filled'. Pretty simple, and this listing-edges approach would work equally well for triangles, hexagons, etc., although both the model and view model would be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

Koncept solution number 1

Create a "BOX" class which is a SKSpriteNode subclass. The BOX class has 4 points or 4 lines. I think it will be enought if you have only 4 points (which the user has clicked). 
Now keep in mind that the user might click on 4 different places creating 4 points which CAN NOT be connected into a box , rather some other complex body. This is the reason I suggested creating a seperate class. In this BOX class you can check now if the four dots are "connectable" and if they are, draw the lines and automatically ensure you truelly have a BOX. 
You could initialize the BOX object with 4 dots. Inside the:

`initWith ... firstDot:(CGPoint)dot1 ...`

you can then check for the coordinates x & y. If they form a a BOX return self & draw and if not dont allow creation & drawing.

Koncept solution number 2

You can use your code, and just add a counter which counts the drawn lines. A box consists of 4 lines. In your

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
```

you check if you `counter % 4 == 0` (since there are). This is the most simple principle without checking if the box is drawn correct. I would recommend you write a BOX checking algorithm to be sure since you will most likely need one at anytime.

I hope this will lead you at least one step closer :)